# Caja de texto de varias líneas en Xamarin Forms

Tags: formularios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

estoy empezando a estudiar Xamarin forms y estoy desarrollando un formulario sencillo para guardar unos cuantos datos sobre ordenes de trabajo, pero quisiera saber que control debo usar para utilizar una caja de texto donde pueda  escribir varias lineas o un parrafo que se amplie en la medida que el parrafo salte a la linea siguiente.

Comment: Saludos Erwin, bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo que revises este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento adecuado del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Éxitos con el desarrllo :D

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el Editor.

```
[Xamarin.Forms.RenderWith(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform._EditorRenderer))]
public class Editor : InputView, IEditorController, IElementConfiguration<Editor>, IFontElement
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Referencia: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Editor/

Answer (score 0):

En **XAML**:

```
<Editor BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="comentarios"/>
```

Con esto puedes escribir parrafos solo agregar las viñetas

Comment: <Editor BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="comentarios"/>

Comment: Si quieres que la caja de texto cambie automáticamente de tamaño a medida que escribes en ella, debes agregarle al Editor el atributo ```AutoSize="TextChanges"```